# How many D3DXEffect in usual?

Tags: c++, hlsl, directx-9, d3dx

I have to use several shaders.
In this situation, which way is often prefered?

1. Making several effects
2. Only one effect and several technicque
3. or another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write effects that address a particular purpose, that use similar resources, and expect similar inputs.  Don't try to address all of your rendering needs by stuffing everything into one effect.  Write an effect for general rendering, another to address a desired style like normal mapping, or cube mapping, etc.  If it's a question of applying different shading algorithms, I would say write separate effects.  Tailor your effect to its application and create techniques within it to address a variety of hardware concerns, or runtime conditions.  If you have a simple project that doesn't require industrial strength code, and effect management is a concern, stuff away.  Honestly though do what suits the project best, what is most efficient for your case. . .

Comment: I agree. You should also keep in mind that the more things you keep in one effect file, the more time you spend on compiling it even when you do a small change in one of the techniques.